# How to interpret GARCH parameters?

Tags: interpretation, garch

I use a standard GARCH model:
\begin{align}
r_t&=\sigma_t\epsilon_t\\
\sigma^2_t&=\gamma_0 + \gamma_1 r_{t-1}^2 + \delta_1 \sigma^2_{t-1}
\end{align}

I have different estimates of the coefficients and I need to interpret them. Therefore I am wondering about a nice interpretation, so what does $\gamma_0$,$\gamma_1$ and $\delta_1$ represent?

I see that $\gamma_0$ is something like a constant part. So it represents kind of an "ambient volatility". The $\gamma_1$ represents the adjustment to past shocks. Also, the $\delta_1$ is not very intuitively for me: It represents the adjustment to pas volatility. But I would like to have a better and more comprehensive interpretation of these parameters.

So can anyone give me a good explanation of what those parameters represent and how a change in the parameters could be explained (so what does it mean if e.g. the $\gamma_1$ increases?).

Also, I looked it up in several books (e.g. in Tsay), but I could not find good information, so any literature recommendation about the interpretation of these parameters would be appreciated.

Edit: I would be also interested in how to interpret the persistence. 
So what is exactly persistence?

In some books I read, that the persistence of a GARCH(1,1) is $\gamma_1+\delta_1$, but e.g. in the book by [Carol Alexander](http://www.amazon.de/Market-Risk-Analysis-Financial-Instruments/dp/B009NNW5A8) on page 283 he talks about only the $\beta$ parameter (my $\delta_1$) being the persistence parameter. So is there a difference between persistence in volatility ($\sigma_t$) and persistence in shocks ($r_t$)?

[image: vo]

Comment: vol-of-vol would be 'volatility of volatility'; the volatility can jump around more.

Comment: shouldn't this be moved to quant finance beta?

Comment: StatTistician, why define $r_t$ at the start only to call the same quantity $a_t$ on the very next line? You don't need two symbols for the same thing.

Comment: I think mean equation should be $r_t$ = $\mu$ + $\sigma_t\epsilon_t$

Comment: I removed $a_t$ from the text, since it is superfluous and makes the GARCH(1,1) definition in the question be a non-standard one.

Answer (score 4):

[Campbell et al](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691043019) (1996) have following interpretation on p. 483.

$\gamma_1$ measures the extent to which a volatility shock today feeds through into next period’s volatility and $\gamma_1 + \delta_1$ measures the rate at which this effect dies over time.

According to [Chan (2010)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470583622) persistence of volatility occurs when $\gamma_1 + \delta_1 = 1$ ,and thus $a_t$ is non-stationary process. This is also called as IGARCH (Integrated GARCH). Under this scenario, unconditional variance become infinite (p. 110)

Note: GARCH(1,1) can be written in the form of ARMA (1,1) to show that the persistence is given by the sum of the parameters (proof in p. 110 of [Chan (2010)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470583622) and p. 483 in Campbell et al (1996). Also, $a^2_{t-1} - \sigma^2_{t-1}$ is now the volatility shock.

Comment: *GARCH(1,1) can be written in the form of ARMA (1,1)*: more precisely, a GARCH(1,1) for $r_t$ can be written as ARMA(1,1) for $r_t^2$ (not for $r_t$).

Answer (score 0):

the large values of the third coefficient ($\delta_{1}$) means that large changes in the volatility will affect future volatilizes for a long period of time since the decay is slower.

Comment: Sandile, I have taken the liberty of making your answer super explicit by including the term your reference.

Comment: What do you think of the preceding answer, then? @Metrics explicitely gave an interpretation for $\gamma_1+\delta_1$, and not $\delta_1$ in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

Alpha catches the arch effect
Beeta catches the garch effect
Sum of both more close to 1, implies volatility remains long

Answer (score 0):

Alpha (ARCH term) represents how volatility reacts to new information
Beta (GARCH Term) represents persistence of the volatility
Alpha + Beta shows overall measurement of persistence of volatility